# Loop basics on a game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on this practice task which is a quiz, scenario is if the answers is wrong the to question.. player can attempt to try again but once I have input the correct answer it will run the question again and not the next one. It's repeating the question all over.

Any idea how can I retain the same question if it's wrong and once corrected it will move to the next question and if the player didnt answer it correctly on the given retries it will move onto the next question?

Heres my code:

```
print("USE FUNCTION --> game()")
def main():
    pass


qs = ["Grass", "Horn", "Feather", "Laugh", "Smooth", "Mountain", "Abundance", "absorb", "cheapskate", "citizenship", "classify", "kingdom", "kilometer", "poet", "free"]
an = ["damo", "sungay", "balihibo", "tawa", "makinis", "bundok", "kasaganahan", "sipsipin", "barat", "pagkamamamayan", "suriin", "kaharian", "kilometro", "makata", "malaya"]


##def attempt():
##    count = 0
##    att = input("Ilagay ang iyong sagot: ")     
##    
##        print("Mali ang iyong sagot, Subukan Muli")
##        break

def game():
    print("---------------------------------")
    print("Welcome to game DAY 2 Quiz - Translate English to Tagalog")
    print("---------------------------------\n")

    score = 0
    count = 0

#Select I then use range staring from 0 till the end minus
    while count < 3: 
        for i in range (0,3):
            student = input(qs[i]+ "\n Ilagay ang iyong sagot: ").upper()
    ##        while count < 3:

            if student == an[i].upper():
                print("Correct\n")
                score += 1

            else:
                print("\n Wrong! Try Again\n")
                print("Attempt",count)
                count += 1
            break

    print("Ang tamang sagot ay",an[i])
    name = input("What is you name: ").upper()            
    print("Hey!",name,"Your final score is",score,"out of 15\n")
    input("Press ENTER to exit")
```

Thanks

Comment: for one thing you should do `if student.upper() == an[i].upper():` instead of `if student == an[i].upper():`

Comment: your `for` loop will actually `break` after every first iteration. not sure why that is there?

Answer (score 0):

reverse the for loop & while loop

looks like you're handling retry count with "while count < 3"

and questions with "for i in range (0,3)"

```
#if you want to go through all questions, try len(qs)
for i in range (0,3): 
    #reset your retry count?
    count = 0
    while count < 3:

        student = input(qs[i]+ "\n Ilagay ang iyong sagot: ").upper()
##        while count < 3:

        if student == an[i].upper():
            print("Correct\n")
            score += 1
            break #<-instead, break here
        else:
            print("\n Wrong! Try Again\n")
            print("Attempt",count)
            count += 1

        #break <-no need to break here
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you play with the loops and conditions!
Try this:

```
qs = ["Grass", "Horn", "Feather", "Laugh", "Smooth", "Mountain", "Abundance", "absorb", "cheapskate", "citizenship", "classify", "kingdom", "kilometer", "poet", "free"]
an = ["damo", "sungay", "balihibo", "tawa", "makinis", "bundok", "kasaganahan", "sipsipin", "barat", "pagkamamamayan", "suriin", "kaharian", "kilometro", "makata", "malaya"]

i, score = 0, 0
main_bucle = True

while main_bucle:

    count = 0

    if i == 15:
        break
    else:
        i+=1

    print(qs[i-1]+ "\nIlagay ang iyong sagot: ")

    while count < 3:

        print("Attempt: " + str(count+1))

        answ = input().upper()

        if answ == an[i-1].upper():
            print("\nCorrect!\n")
            score += 1
            break

        else:
            print("\nWrong! Try Again\n")
            count+=1

print("You score is: " + str(score))
```